# How to highlight days from API in highlighable calendar in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, api, date, kotlin

I have API that post and get dates:

this is the data class:

```
data class PlannerGet(
val date: String,
val endTime: String,
val id: Int,
val location: String,
val note: String,
val startTime: String,
val title: String
)
```

and i am using this library for the calendar:
https://github.com/VarunBarad/Highlightable-Calendar-View

now in the fragment i was able to highlight certain days like this:

```
HighlightableCalendarView.dayDecorators = listOf(
        DayDecorator(
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4)
            },
            Color.parseColor("#ffffff"),
            Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
        ),
    )
```

but i want to highlight the days from API
i tried to make it like this:

```
HighlightableCalendarView.dayDecorators = listOf(
        DayDecorator(
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(PlannerGet.date)
            },
            Color.parseColor("#ffffff"),
            Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
        ),
    )
```

but i am having a problem with "set" it show "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

i tried to add "toInt()" and still the same problem.

what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
if (response?.body().toString() == "[]") {


            }

            else if (response.isSuccessful) {

                response.body()?.forEach {

                    getplanner.add(it)
                    Log.e("gggg gggg",getplanner.toString())
                    Log.e("gggg ddddd",getplanner[0].date)

                }

                val list = arrayListOf<DayDecorator>()

                for (dsds in getplanner) {



                    list.add( DayDecorator(
                        Calendar.getInstance().apply {

                            //  getplanner[0].date
                            val input_date = dsds.date
                            val format1 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                            var dt1: Date? = null

                            dt1 = format1.parse(input_date)
                            val format2: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd")
                            val strMonth: String = format2.format(dt1)
                            val month = strMonth.toInt()
                            Log.e("dateinplanner", "" + month)

                            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, month)

                        },
                        Color.parseColor("#ffffff"),
                        Color.parseColor("#1AB7B8")

                    ))

                }



                HighlightableCalendarView.dayDecorators = list
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the params which you are passing do not match the required params.

```
 Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4)
        }
```

The set functions accept the **int field, int value** but you are passing the params as the string

```
PlannerGet.date
```

The function set

```
public void set(int field, int value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

If you want the date to be passed from the API dates please convert the string dates to java Date object.